# How do you reset all of Finder's settings?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, settings, plist

How do you reset all of the settings related to the Sidebar, general preferences, default folder views, etc? Deleting `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` does not seem to reset the sidebar. Also, that file does not recreate itself. Deleting `com.apple.finder.plist` will not reset the default view for every folder. Also, deleting `.DS_Store` will only reset the layout of folders when in icon view. I am running macOS 10.14.6.

Edit: Entering `defaults delete com.apple.finder;killall Finder` will reset the folder view for all of the User's folders, but won't change `/Applications` view.